# Weird "Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on column 'Name' because it is not full-text indexed." error

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have followed the article [here](http://www.entityframework.info/Home/FullTextSearch) to implement Full text search with entity framework.

I have 2 search boxes in my form. One for search can be used for name and number and the other search box is used to search for address.

Some a weird error message I get from the sql server as below:

> Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on column 'Name' because
>   it is not full-text indexed.

But this error is misleading. This is not the real issue. I have already created full text search and added Name, Number, and Address in the catalog.

Then I have run Sql profiler to get the actual SQL query that is generated by EF as below:

```
SELECT 
[Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Project1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Project1].[Number] AS [Number],
[Project1].[Address] AS [Address]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Filter1].[Id1] AS [Id], 
    [Filter1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Filter1].[Number] AS [Number],
    [Filter1].[Address] AS [Address]
    FROM (SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id1],
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name],
    [Extent1].[Number] AS [Number],
    [Extent1].[Address] AS [Address] FROM [dbo].[Company] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Status] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[CompanyStatusId] = [Extent2].[Id]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Category] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent1].[CategoryId] = [Extent4].[Id]
        WHERE [Extent1].[CategoryId] IN (1) ) AS [Filter1]

    WHERE ((contains([Name],'test')) OR (contains([Number], 'test'))) AND (contains([Address], 'blah'))
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[Number] ASC
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

When I run the query I get the same error. I cannot figure out where the actual issue is with this query.

I am not sure why EF is generating very complex query and sub queries which seems to me redundant but beside that I cannot figure out what the the underline issue with this query.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: "This is not the real issue." Consider the possibility that it is. See if a simple manual query like `SELECT * FROM dbo.Company WHERE CONTAINS([Name], 'test')` gives the error as well. If it does, follow any troubleshooting instructions for full-text indexing.

Comment: Well I have already tested the fulltext seach index and it works fine. Just the query above gives error.

Comment: Then continue making the initial test query more complicated until you've found the breaking spot. Does `SELECT * FROM (SELECT Name FROM dbo.Company) T WHERE Contains(T.[Name], 'test')` work? That's using a subquery, just like EF.

Comment: No. This query doesn't work and I get the same exception. So does that mean full text search cannot be used in sub queries?

Comment: Apparently, yes, the optimizer can't "see through" the source of the column. (No, I don't know how exactly how full-text search works myself.) You can't stop EF from generating subqueries, but you may be able to ensure it only puts the predicates in the inner queries. (I don't know exactly how EF works either.)

Comment: I cannot believe that there is no support for fts in EF yet. and I cannot believe no one had this issue before and have a solution for it :) Thanks anyway. I will keep looking a solution or maybe to use stored procedure instead.

Comment: If EF supported FTS natively, the logical place would be in [`SqlFunctions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.entity.sqlserver.sqlfunctions), but there is no `SqlFunctions.Contains`. Nor does there seem to be much progress on things like this in [EF Core](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2850).

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this error when using that FtsInterceptor code you linked to, but only when using a query that joined enough tables to make the contains clause refer to a [Filter] column, as in `(contains([Filter1].[Title], @p__linq__0)`. Your query doesn't include the column name in the contains function for some reason, but from the nesting it does look like it's probably inferring the `[Filter1]` alias.

Anyway, what seemed to fix the problem for me was moving the Contains clause, i.e. `query.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(fts))`, to the very top of the query so that it was the first clause. This changed it to use the `[Extent1]` table, as in `(contains([Extent1].[Title], @p__linq__0)`, which worked.